# How to Tie Martial Arts Headgear for Boxing, Muay Thai, etc

Tags: training, mixed-martial-arts, boxing, muay-thai, equipment

Does anyone have Step by Step instructions on how to tie boxing head gear? Enclosed below are two pieces. Can someone post 4-5 picture instructions on how to tie and lace properly? When it came out of the box, it fell out, and I can't remember anymore, I took couple guesses, just want to be sure .

I do not see many "How to Tie Headgear" videos on youtube surprisingly, only this, however it does not show back side of the head. There many videos on how to tie boxing hand wraps .

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6xZbdJ4Cky4

[image]

Person who posts, obviously doesn't need to post actual picture of themselves. Just basically how to lace, and tie up equipment, over a couple series, I will figure out the rest. Thanks

Comment: Could you tell us the model of the headgear?

Comment: hi @MacacoBranco Its Sanabul, I left the brand name out on purpose as most head gears have the similar pieces above  , https://www.amazon.com/Sanabul-Essential-Professional-Boxing-Kickboxing/dp/B0788MSGK9

Comment: Hi @MacacoBranco can you delete the spam answer below? Thanks